# Understanding brackets in python dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python 2.7, and have been learning by borrowing python books from the library that are probably too advanced, but they are all they have.  I'm trying to break apart a code from *Think Compexity* by O'Reilly, about dictionary of dictionaries as below:

```
class Graph(dict):
    """A Graph is a dictionary of dictionaries.  The outer
    dictionary maps from a vertex to an inner dictionary.
    The inner dictionary maps from other vertices to edges.

    For vertices a and b, graph[a][b] maps
    to the edge that connects a->b, if it exists."""

    def __init__(self, vs=[], es=[]):
        """Creates a new graph.  
        vs: list of vertices;
        es: list of edges.
        """
        for v in vs:
            self.add_vertex(v)

        for e in es:
            self.add_edge(e)

    def add_vertex(self, v):
        """Add a vertex to the graph."""
        self[v] = {}

    def add_edge(self, e):
        """Adds and edge to the graph by adding an entry in both directions.

        If there is already an edge connecting these Vertices, the
        new edge replaces it.
        """
        v, w = e
        self[v][w] = e
        self[w][v] = e
```

I am having trouble understanding what the code inside brackets do, as in `def __init__(self, vs=[], es=[])`.  I get it assigns properties, and "vs" and "es" are lists, but why aren't these declared inside the function? Why is "self" there?  Same for `def add_vertex(self, v)` and `def add_edge(self, e)`.

Can't the lists be declared inside the function using the following?

```
vs = {}
```

Comment: You should be reading [Learning Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do) and learn the basics about Python, especially arguments (chapter 18 - relates to your `vs`/`es` question) and classes/OOP (Part VI - relates to your `self` question).

Answer (score 0):

`vs` and `es` are arguments used when initializing an instance of the `Graph` class. If you define them inside `__init__` they will always be the same when initializing an instance. `[]` is the default value when no arguments are passed by the user. Examples:

```
d1 = Graph(vs=[1,2])               #Creates a graph with 2 vertices, no edges
d2 = Graph(vs=[1,2,3], es=[(1,3)]) #Creates a graph with 3 vertices,  1 edge
```

In case you weren't able to specify `vs` and `es` upon initialization you would have to do the following:

```
d1 = Graph()          #Creates blank graph
d1.add_vertex(1)      #Adds vertex 1
d1.add_vertex(2)      #Adds vertex 2
d1 == Graph(vs=[1,2]) #Returns True

d2 = Graph()
d2.add_vertex(1)      #Adds vertex 1
d2.add_vertex(2)      #Adds vertex 2
d2.add_vertex(3)      #Adds vertex 3
d2.add_edge((1,3))    #Adds edge between vertex 1 and 3
d2 == Graph(vs=[1,2,3], es=[(1,3)])  #Returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` is included in this function declaration and the others as Python doesn't pass `self` implicitly like most other object languages, instead it passes it explicitly, as does Perl:

```
def __init__(self, vs=[], es=[]):
```

The `vs` and `es` are simply formal parameters to the function, think of it this way:

```
def __init__(self, vs, es):
```

The `=[]` part are default values, simply empty lists to keep the code from breaking if the optional arguments aren't supplied.

Answer (score 0):

`vs=[]` and `es=[]` are argument declarations with **default values**. Should any of them be omitted in the call to `__init__`, it will default to an empty list. `self` is the instance itself. You see, `__init__` is not a constructor but an initialization function; the instance is constructed *before* `__init__` is called.

(The name `self` is conventional; it could be `this` or anything at all. All *instance methods* receive the instance as their first argument).

The arguments `vs` and `es` are respectively a list of vertices and a list of edges supplied at construction time (i.e., `Graph(...)`). A cursory examination of the code makes be think that an edge is a tuple `(v1, v2)`, where `v1` and `v2` are vertices. `Graph` is a dictionary whose keys are *from* vertices; each vertex maps to a dictionary whose keys are *to* vertices. The existence of a value associated with `self[a][b]` means that there is an edge `a->b`; the code implies that `self[a][b] == self[b][a] == (a,b)`.

Doing
`vs={}` would create a *local name* `vs` referring to an empty dictionary (`vs=[]` would make `vs` refer to an empty list). A formal parameter is also a local name, but it is a local name **initialized at call time**.